How to test apis via postman/bruno secured using oauth2?
I am using Spring Boot to create an api server. I am doing authentication via Google OAuth by following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2. The guide uses Spring Boot as the client, and has a HTML button that calls /oauth2/authorization/googleto authenticate with Google.
This works great, but the problem comes when I want to test my apis using a software like postman or bruno. My apis require knowing the logged in user's details, so I need to send the authentication details and cannot simply disable security during development.
I found a workaround, which is to login via the button from the frontend, manually copy the JSESSIONID cookie from my browser, and insert in into my header in postman/bruno. This does not feel like the right approach. I tried getting the access token from Google directly, and sending it as a auth bearer token but my server always returns 401.

This question is similar to: Able to hit the secured endpoint from browser but not from postman/insomnia getting 401 unathorized. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, access tokens from Google only have Google as audience => you should not even try to use it to authorize requests to your APIs (anyhow, it is opaque and will ruin performance if you configure a resource server to introspect it on the userinfo endpoint). Put an authorization server of your own in front of Google if you intend to set up a resource server. on-premise solutions like Keycloak, cloud offers like Auth0, and do-it-yourself like Spring Authorization Server are frequent choices (the last requiring more OAuth2 knowledge than you probably have)
